# Display results of a query in a table in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 models as below.

Model for Item

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :item_type, :class_name=>ItemType, :foreign_key=>"item_type_id"
end
```

and Model for Ingredients

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
    validates_presence_of :ingredient, :message=>"name cannot be blank!"
end
```

and model for recipe_ingredients

```
class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item, :class_name=>Item, :foreign_key=>"item_id"
  belongs_to :ingredient, :class_name=>Ingredient, :foreign_key=>"ingredient_id"
  validates_numericality_of :quantity
end
```

---

The table for ingredients has following columns

```
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
"ingredient" varchar, 
"inventory_unit" varchar, 
"recipe_unit" varchar, 
"created_at" datetime NOT NULL, 
"updated_at" datetime NOT NULL
```

---

The view for index of recipe ingredients is as below. The ingredients are appearing in the view. I want to pull recipe unit from ingredients table for the selected ingredient and display it in the table. I have tried it doing a query. The code is as below.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Recipe Ingredients</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Ingredient</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @recipe_ingredients.each do |recipe_ingredient| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= recipe_ingredient.item %></td>
        <td><%= recipe_ingredient.ingredient.ingredient %></td>
        <td><%= recipe_ingredient.quantity %></td>
        <td><%= Ingredient.select('recipe_unit').where(:id => @ingredient_id) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', recipe_ingredient %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_recipe_ingredient_path(recipe_ingredient) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', recipe_ingredient, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Recipe Ingredient', new_recipe_ingredient_path %>
```

---

But the output I am getting is as shown in image given below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply type the following:

```
recipe_ingredient.ingredient.recipe_unit
```

#### Why is this possible?

Since a `RecipeIngredient` belongs_to an `Ingredient`, you can access the `Ingredient` of a `RecipeIngredient` as if it was any other field like this:

```
recipe_ingredient.ingredient
```

Once you have the ingredient, you can pull the recipe_unit directly by typing:

```
recipe_ingredient.ingredient.recipe_unit
```

#### Side note:

You can omit the `:class_name` and `:foreign_key` hashes from your associativity rules in your model classes. For example, take this class:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to Course
end
```

By convention, rails will associate the Student class with the Course class. Rails will look for a column in the "students" database table labeled "course_id", and if "course_id" exists as a column in the table, Rails will automatically use that field as the foreign key for Student. You can use the `:foreign_key => 'some_key'` notation when you want to override the default conventions in rails (which isn't recommended unless its strictly necessary).

For more reading on the subject of active record migrations and foreign key associations, you can check out the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's displaying as it is because you are displaying the whole class, not an actual detail of the instance.

In this case below, you are selecting a whole set of Ingredients (the set contains only one ingredient, but it will always return a set):

```
Ingredient.select('recipe_unit').where(:id => @ingredient_id)
```

What you probably want is something like this:

```
Ingredient.find(@ingredient_id).recipe_unit
```

The differences:

1. where always returns a set of items (even if there's just one item in the set) What is returned is not an ingredient, but an Active Relation. To just return one ingredient, you need to use `find` or `first` (or a similar such method).
2. `select` just tells Rails what to pull out of the db... it doesn't tell the template what to display in the template. It says "only fetch the `recipe_unit` column from the db" it doesn't say `and then output the`recipe_unit`column` - for that you need to actually call the `recipe_unit` method on the ingredient (as in the example I gave).

Note that you have the same problem with `recipe_ingredient.item`
What column from an item do you want to display? does it have a `name` or a `description` if so - you need to actually call that eg:

```
<%= recipe_ingredient.item.name %>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you may omit `:class_name` and `:foreign_key` from your models because of [convention over configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#convention-over-configuration-in-active-record) - your models are named exactly like classes and foreign keys you list.

As for your question, you need to use [yak shaving](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2012/1/4/yak-shaving) for that:

```
recipe_ingredient.ingredient.recipe_unit
```